# How to re-send (read) an old kafka message from given topic and partition at specific offset using spring-kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Given topic name, partition number and offset, how can I read just one record from the topic?

In my Sprng Boot based application I use Kafka for import of business data.
Import records are send to *import_queue* and consumed by one or more business modules. Records are always acknowledged even if consumer fails to import data from the record in order to continue data import from the following records.

Later a user (after he/she has fixed some dependent business data) can decide to re-send one or more failed (but acknowledged) import records.

The offset, partition number and topic name of every record are stored in my application internally in an SQL database.

From the reference documentation and some StackOverflow questions I found out that I have to:

1. set-up a container (consumer/listener)
2. rewind (seek) to desired offset
3. read one record
4. skip reading remaining records

Is this the only way to read just one old record from a kafka topic? 
Or is there an easier solution?

### Solution

As suggested by @Gary:

```
ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> read(String topic, int partition, long offset) {
    Map<String, Object> configs = Map.of(
            "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092",
            "group.id", "incubator_retry",
            "max.poll.records", 1);
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<byte[], byte[]> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            configs, new ByteArrayDeserializer(), new ByteArrayDeserializer());

    try (Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer()) {
        TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
        consumer.assign(List.of(topicPartition));
        consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset);
        ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
        if (consumerRecords.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Timeout polling from topic %s partition %d at offset %d",
                    topicPartition.topic(), topicPartition.partition(), offset));
        }
        return consumerRecords.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier solution.

- Use the `DefaultConsumerFactory` to create a `KafkaConsumer` (or simply create one)
- Use a different `group.id`
- Set the `max.poll.records` property to 1
- `consumer.assign(...)` the desired topic/partition
- `seek(...)` to the required offset
- `poll(...)` until you get the record
- `close()` the consumer

If you are using any message conversion (aside from Kafka deserializers) you will have to invoke the converter manually.